# Network Load On VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp

I have four locations that are very rural and have limited network reliability and speed.  Our Main Office has our server, people and several other devices on a LAN.  Each remote site has a couple devices and a couple people.  We don't have an option to increase speed at any location.

We would like to VPN these together at the Main Office but I am worried that this will bring the network to its knees since the Main Office with the bulk of the computers and activity has such a poor (0.75 MB) upload speed.

Am I correct in assuming that if I connect the remote locations to a VPN located in the main office that all traffic, including web surfing and the like must pass through the Main Office?  Would this limit all machines to a shared 0.75 MB in speed?  I have included a very simple diagram of our layout.

[A simple visual of our mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRPLf.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not necessarily true. The route traffic takes depends on the routing tables configured in the routers at the satellite offices. Given the fixed nature of your network, I would recommending managing your routes statically. Only route internal traffic by VPN. The specific procedures for setting up static routes would depend on the routers you are using.

Also, you may want to establish tunnels directly between sites (3 tunnels per site) so that the main office doesn't have to route between the other offices. You could also define 'Remote-B' to be the main VPN head end since it has the most bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

What @andy said is good advice - set up a mesh of tunnels and route traffic directly between hosts and don't set a default gateway so non-intranet traffic does not traverse the VPN. I wanted to add some additional considerations -

1. Be careful of VPN choice. PPTP, for example is totally broken and a bad choice.
2. VPN adds overhead to connections so reduces the available bandwidth.
3. Some VPNs (like OpenVPN) allow for compression of packets which can often more then compensate for VPN overheads, the extent depends on the traffic going over them - encrypted traffic like ssh and https won't see a decrease in anything except the packet and encapsulation overheads.
4. Assuming your connections are asymmetrical like ADSL, hosting common content "in the cloud" (aka on other people's servers which are better connected), eg mail server, file server assuming it's small files that need to be equally accessible anywhere. **You could also simplify your network by having single VPNs from each site into the cloud rather then a mesh solution.**